# Сохранить данные из HTML-формы в файл c помощью js

Tags: javascript

Сохранить данные из HTML-формы в файл c помощью js как можно осуществить на клиенте ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если без видимости клиенту, то копайте в сторону cookie или localdb.

Comment: чисто на клиенте никак (безопасность), надо привлекать сервер (например AJAX), или вроде как читал с помощью JAVA-аплетов можно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для сериализации формы можно использовать метод [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/) `.serialize()`, вот так:

```
$("form").serialize();
```

Для сохранения файла на стороне клиента можно использовать библиотеку [FileSaver](https://github.com/koffsyrup/FileSaver.js)

Добавляем код для преобразования текста в байты:

```
function data2blob(data, isBase64) {
    var chars = "";
    if (isBase64)
        chars = atob(data);
    else
        chars = data;
    var bytes = new Array(chars.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        bytes[i] = chars.charCodeAt(i);
    var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(bytes)]);
    return blob;
}
```

Сохраняем:

```
saveAs(data2blob($("form").serialize()), "myString.txt");
```

**Обновление:**

Чтобы загрузить из файла нужно добавить кнопку загрузки:

```
<input type="file" id="fileToLoad" accept="text/plain" />
```

Далее создаем функцию которая будет заниматься загрузкой:

```
function loadFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(){
     var dataURL = reader.result;
     var data = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(dataURL).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}');

     mapJson(data) ;
  };
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
}
```

Особое внимание стоит обратить вот на это:

```
JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(dataURL).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}');
```

Этот код используется для превращения строки из dataURL формата в JSON. По факту это лишнее, если сохранить файл сразу в JSON.

Далее добавляем функцию маппер, которая будет заниматься присваиванием значений обратно:

```
function mapJson(data) {
      for (var i in data) {
       $('form input[name="'+i+'"],form  select[name="'+i+'"]').val(data[i]);
    }
}
```

Полный пример на [jsFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/9qo85qwr/6/).

**Обновление 2:**

В примере выше некорректно работают checkbox, пришлось внести некоторые изменения.

Добавил свою сериализацию:

```
function getJson(form) {
    var result = {};
    form.find("input, select").each(function (index, element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var name = $element.attr("name");
        if (!name)
            return true;

        if ($element.is("input[type='checkbox']")) {
            result[name] = $element.prop("checked");
        } else if ($element.is("input[type='radio']")) {
            if (!result[name]) {
                result[name] = []
            }
            result[name].push($element.prop("checked"));
        } else {
            result[name] = $element.val();
        }
    });
    return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Изменил маппер:

```
function mapJson(form, data) {
    for (var name in data) {
        var $element = form.find('input[name="' + name + '"],select[name="' + name + '"]');
        if ($element.is("input[type='checkbox']")) {
            $element.prop("checked", data[name] || false);
        } else if ($element.is("input[type='radio']")) {
            $element.each(function(index, value){
                $(value).prop("checked", data[name][index] || false);
            });
        } else {
            $element.val(data[name]);
        }

    }
}
```

Загрузка из файла теперь выглятит так:

```
reader.onload = function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(reader.result);
    mapJson(data);
}
```

[Рабочий пример.](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/uv8wssyj/)

Comment: Пример на [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/9qo85qwr/1) .

Comment: Вроде как все логично, а можете объяснить например пользователь выбрал 10 select option эти выбранные позиции сохранились в файл. Потом пользователь открывает снова *.html файл и я думаю как сделать так чтобы эти выбранные пункты отобразились в html файле

Comment: @Элиот, смотри обновление, я нашел пару косяков, сейчас исправлю. Вообще это один из вариантов. Можно данные сохранить в [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), все зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: спасибо то что нужно)

Comment: с этим примером каждый раз создается новый файл,  а как можно сделать чтобы если пользователь открыл файл внес изменения(выбрал другой пункт select option) то изменения сохранилось бы в том в файле который пользователь открыл.

Comment: @Элиот это зависит от браузера, **IE** и **Firefox** предложат сохранить как, а вот **Crome** скачает в папку с index++. А так да, загрузили значения из фала->изменили->сохранили в новый файл. Универсализировать поведение можно только с помощью JAVA-аплетов, как выше писали.